# What make this design suitable to use for poetry texts?

Tags: typography, design-principles, typesetting

This is how WordPress formats a block of verse:

[image]

I wonder why does that design suit poetry texts? Why can that combination of typography, spacing, border reflect the poetry effect/ambience?

<sub>Meta discussion: [Are questions about the rationale behind a design choice on-topic?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3610/26474)</sub>

Comment: Being in a language which i can read may make a difference. However, there is nothing in that block of text which inherently conveys "poetry" to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress must have followed some existing guideline. For example, [wikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/Format-a-Poem) instructs the following for preparing poems for publication in a magazine:

> - one inch margins on all sides
> - poem title centered or flush left
> - poems are single spaced
> - Justify and indent the text of your poem.

The font they use in the examples is some Courier variation (monospaced font), and they suggest 12pt.

> **Choose 1-inch (2.5-cm) margins and a 12-point font.** Typically, publications want wide margins so that the text is easier to read. You should also choose a standard font that doesn't distract from the poem. Courier is a good choice, and standard for some publications.

Those guidelines come from [Writer's Digest](https://www.writersdigest.com/writing-articles/by-writing-genre/poetry/prepare_to_submit), which could be where Wordpress got it from.

Comment: Yes. This is the kind of answer I'm looking for. So it seems that the monospaced font isn't chosen because the content is poem, but because it's just a clear font to read